# C# label AutoSize adds padding

Tags: c#, winforms, text, label

I have a Label on a Windows.Form. I set the AutoSize property on the label to True and I noticed that when I do that, it pads the right hand side with ~5px of white background. I have the Padding property set to [0, 0, 0, 0]. Is there a way to get rid of this?

I would like to get the bounds of the label as close as possible to the text within the label.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no way when you use only padding and margin. That's the default behavior.

[image]

In the above `Window` I've set the `Padding` and `Margin` to `[0,0,0,0]`. Those 5 pixels are still there.

If you set `FlatStyle = System` and `AutoSize = False` you can get this:

[image]

In the above `Window` you don't have those 5 pixels anymore.

Comment: Turning off AutoSize will set the label size to a manual amount. Since the text in the label will be changing, it will need to be resized. The AutoSize property does that for me. If there is a way to simulate this property, that would be an acceptable answer as well.

Comment: FlatStyle = System, awesome, that was killing me, thank you! +1

Comment: Could you provide the code you used to get the second window? I keep getting the first window..

Comment: FWIW, this didn't work for me, I keep getting the first window

Comment: Yes, the FlatStyle=System does turn the "internal" padding off -- but the TextAlign property is now completely ignored, regardless if done before or after setting the FlatStyle property.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so FlastStyle = System; AutoSize = false; and then set up a property that will calculate the width like this:

```
public string LabelText
{
    set
    {
        _label.Text = value;
        using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics()) {
            _label.Width = (int)g.MeasureString(_label.Text, _label.Font).Width;
        }
    }
```

}