# Default Padding for Label

Tags: c#, winforms, label

In WinForms , I want to know the empty space applied to label:

[image]

before start of text (*marked with question) as well at the end of text, also you might know It varies as per we change it's font-size, font-family, font style etc. properties.

Is there any formula or proportion in which the empty space is calculated by c#?

Cause I am unable to understand how this space is increased or decreased as we change the font family or font style.

Comment: WebForm? Winforms? WPF? Windows Phone? Metro?

Comment: -1 As @Oded indicates, this question needs context before anyone can give you a reasonable answer.

Comment: I am working on winform application (windows application) where I want to Calculating the empty space.

Comment: Have mercy for this guy. He just joined today. Do you want him to look for other site for his almost closed answer?

Comment: Do you want to remove those spaces?

Comment: Yes I want to remove those spaces / I want to calculate those spaces

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3630031/754438) is how to remove spaces

Comment: I have already tried your suggestion but in my scenario It lessors the space,But Not completely remove. So that's why I have to remove that space or calculate the space for other calculation.

Comment: You might want to add to your question **why** you want to do this. That way, people can give you suggestions to other solutions instead of just how to calculate the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
Graphics.MeasureString(" ", yourFont);
```

suit you? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/6xe5hazb.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also tried Graphics.MeasureString and TextRenderer.MeasureText, but this is not what i m expecting. i just want to calculate the blank space in front and before text in label.

This gap between label boundary and text is varying as per Label size, Alignment, Font Size, Font Family and Font Style. so i m not sure about the required space width. i mentioned one scenario other scenarios will be different as we change one of the above parameters.
can you plz help regarding this ?

Thanking you in anticpaition.

Comment: Basically I am trying to replicate this Label Behavior in my html web page where I am dealing with div,span(html control), I want to apply this Behavior to my div. So when I am showing text in to div by taking input from text box So,It will dynamically have space.

Answer (score -1):

For winforms, Padding Property is where to specify the interior spacing of the control.

`Label.Padding.Left`
and 
`Label.Padding.Right`

Comment: I have used these properties but it returns me Padding zero and Label Control has Specific default padding in which I am interested.I want to know that padding value.

Comment: It would be great if you let me know what you trying to do, there are several reason when you change the Padding it returns me to Zero , such as there is `auto resize` enabled.